# Xcode 7 can't find header of imported 3rd party frameworks

Tags: xcode, frameworks, header

I'm trying to add some frameworks from qt to my xcode project, but xcode can not find framework header files, say `<QtCore/QCoreApllication>`.

I have added the path of frameworks' folder path to project setting's `Framework Search Path` and `Library Search Path`. I have added my frameworks to project setting's `Link Binary WithLibraries`

So what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understand that reason of problem consists in that Xcode or clang compiler caches framework search path (always one path in clang -F directive despite of my changes in xcode build settings). There are some information in [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4) that can be useful. I tried to clear some of mentioned folders but it didn't help me.
So what helped me, it is a creation of new mac user :)